# What does it mean "In love’s service only wounded soldiers can serve."?

Tags: grammar

I just read this quote from [nytimes's opinion section](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/06/24/opinion/david-brooks-rhapsody-in-realism.html?_r=0).

"In love’s service only wounded soldiers can serve."

What does this quote mean? I can faintly feel what it means, but I want to understand it more clearly. Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Lit Crit" interpretation of highly metaphoric non-idiomatic poetic/literary text. [Here's a discussion](http://remindsmeofyou.org/tag/testimony/) of the original usage as cited by your text. It's all subjective.

Comment: Oops, I didn't know about the scope stuff. Sorry for asking off-topic question.

Comment: This is probably one of those cases where it could be extremely difficult for a learner to recognise that the text causing difficulties involves obscure literary references and/or poetic usages (as opposed to *idiomatic* usages that may be perfectly familiar to most native speakers). I've no solid grounds for disagreeing with J.R.'s interpretation (essentially, "We're all imperfect, including lovers"). But maybe it's more specifically pointing out that you can only *truly* love if you've been *hurt by love* (better to have loved and lost, and all that). As I said, it's all highly subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Having just read how the *NY Times* opinion piece concludes with this quote, it seems to be emphasizing how, in the context of love relationships, none of us are perfect, and we need to learn to deal with that.

*Service* in this context refers to *military service*. Metaphors to military enlistment are not uncommon (something probably not constrained to English); this is one of them. Anyone who has fallen in love is now "in love's service", serving alongside a fellow soldier. Both of those soldiers are *wounded,* which simply alludes to their imperfection.

A similar way to say the same thing might be:

> On the assembly line of love, we are all faulty goods.

(The metaphor is changed from *military service* to *manufacturing*.)

<sub>I may have not got this 100% right from a literary interpretation, but I feel like my English interpretation is sound.</sub>

Comment: Thanks J.R.♦, I really appreciate your help! This really helped me. :)

Comment: To me, the metaphor is, "In marriage (love's service), one can only survive (nay, "thrive") by accepting (and forgiving) the wounds that necessarily occur in such a surviving/thriving relationship."